# What problem at GeoServer?

Tags: geoserver

I use GeoServer version 2.7.0 and Apache Tomcat 7.0.
I want to delete default data because it is very dirty to see.
So I clicked delete button. Then I got popup but it is empty.
What problem at GeoServer?
[image]

Comment: Did the cite data get removed from your data directory?

Comment: No . I did not remove data.

Comment: But was it deleted on click

Comment: GeoServer 2.7.x has been unsupported for many years. The current supported version is 2.13.x

Comment: Perhaps there is no translation of the message in your language. Changing into English could give better description.